# Concurrent C++11 - Which toolchains can be used?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, c++11, lock-free

I use `<thread> <atomic> <mutex>` etc heavily in my code, which includes several lock-free algorithms. I am targeting (eventually) a linux environment. I've been developing with the Visual Studio 2011 Beta, which while lacking horribly in other C++11 features, seems to be the only toolchain that implements the concurrent features.

See c++ 11 support here:

- [Clang 3+](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)
- [GCC 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)
- [MSVC 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

Now if the others simply lack a library containing the c++ 11 concurrent features, I can easily use [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/), however both clang and gcc answer "no" to the c++11 memory model, which at least visual c++ seems to support. I'm not exactly sure what the effect of this would be - probably optimizing away of apparently side effect free code, among other erroneous things.

If for now I completely avoid optimized builds and compile only debug builds without optimizations enabled - is it reasonable to use the Clang or GCC toolchain?

Comment: My immediate guess is that if you use `just::thread`, it'll work fine. It uses the native (Posix or Win32) primitives to enforce things like ordering, so I think a compiler would have to be pretty badly broken in general for it to fail.

Comment: You should probably include a multi-threaded related tag in your list, Anthony Williams regularly show up here, so if you are lucky enough he'll notice then. I think that he created `just::thread` so that it would be cross-platform, so I would not expect any issue.

Answer (score 4):

> [GCC 4.7 status](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM)
>
> C++ memory model work is ongoing and scheduled for completion in the
>   next GCC release. GCC 4.7 has now been released, so this is what you
>   can expect from it.
>
> - Full atomic implementation for supported lock free instructions. All the atomic operations have been implemented with the new __atomic
>     builtins, and most targets reflect the memory model parameter in the
>     code which is generated. Optimizations will not move shared memory
>     operations past atomic operations, so the various happens
>     relationships are honoured.
> - When lock free instructions are not available (either through hardware or OS support) atomic operations are left as function calls
>     to be resolved by a library. Due to time constraints and an API which
>     is not finalized, there is no libatomic supplied with GCC 4.7. This is
>     easily determined by encountering unsatisfied external symbols
>     beginning with _*atomic**.
> - Should a program require library assistance, a single C file sample implementation is available to be compiled and linked in with the
>     client program to resolve these external function calls using a locked
>     implementation. Download sample libatomic
> - C++ templates fully support arbitrary sized objects, althought the previously mentioned libatomic.c file may be required to satisfy some
>     user defined classes. If a class maps to the same size as a supported
>     lock-free integral type, then lock-free routines will be used as well.
> - Bitfields are not compliant with the memory model. That is to say that they may introduce load or store data races due to whole word
>     accesses when reading or writing.
> - Optimizations have not been fully audited for compliance, although some work has been done. Some optimizations may introduce new data
>     races which were not present before. The number of known cases are
>     small, and testing for compliance is not trivial. If anyone encounters
>     a case where an optimization introduces a new data race, please open a
>     bugzilla case for it so it can be addressed.

---

Support in LLVM seems to be further along: http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/Atomics.html

It's hard to tell to what degree this is actually used in clang though. It seems like `<atomic>` basically works for some types. I'm getting compiler assertions for other types saying that the atomic type was unexpected, which gives a bit of confidence for the types it does work with.

Comment: This looks promising. I'm actually leaning toward clang because it seems to produce more helpful error messages - and that's a substantial time sync for me with c++. There's a experimental QtCreator that uses clang to implement the code model (completion, highlighting, refactorings, etc.) I'm going to give that a try, since I really miss my visual studio + visual assist x on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have used gcc-4.7 on 64 bit linux and windows with success. `std::thread` etc. works perfect on linux even with gcc-4.6.
On windows gcc-4.7 (mingw64) has some minor issues, memory leaks with destructors of `std::condition_variable` AFAIR.